# How would I iterate through a list and replace objects that are repeated?

Tags: python-3.x, loops

I am trying to go through a list and have each object in that list compared with the others, and all repetitions of it replaced with something else.

```
>>> t = [1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4]
>>> for i in range(len(t)):
num = t[i]
if num in t[i+1:]:
    num = 'cherry'
```

This is not turning the repeated ints into 'cherry'. I know that I am referring to them correctly as I put print(num) in place of num = cherry and it is printing what I want. It will not reassign them, though. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `num = 'cherry'` says nothing at all about `t`, it just reassigns the name `num`. If you want to change the list, `t` must appear in the left-hand side of the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

You should make the list a set because sets are unordered collections of unique elements and are great for removing duplicates from a sequence
To make a set use either the set() function like in the code below or use curly braces {} like the output

```
t = [1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4]
x = set(t)
print(x)
#Output
{1, 2, 4}
```